# Hibernate and Mysql gives "Geometry byte string must be little endian." error

Tags: spatial-analyst, mysql, hibernate-spatial, mysql-spatial

I'm using mysql and wildly.

I want to look for points in a given polygon. My method looks like:

```
public Response getGeoJsonByBox(
                                    @QueryParam("topLeftX") double topLeftX,
                                    @QueryParam("bottomRightX") double bottomRightX,
                                    @QueryParam("topLeftY") double topLeftY,
                                    @QueryParam("bottomRightY") double bottomRightY) {

        Envelope viewPort = new Envelope(topLeftX, bottomRightX, topLeftY, bottomRightY);
        List<Stammdaten> stammdatenList = em.createQuery("select s from Stammdaten s where contains(:viewPort, s.coordinate) = true")
                .setParameter("viewPort", viewPort)
                .getResultList();
return stammdatenList;}
```

But I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Geometry byte string must be little endian.
```

My Entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner_stammdaten")
@XmlRootElement(name = "stammdaten")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NamedQuery(name = Stammdaten.all, query = "SELECT s from Stammdaten s")
public class Stammdaten extends GeoJson
        {

    public static final String all = "all";
    public static final String viewPort = "getByViewPort";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String strasse;
    @XmlElement
    private String hausnummer;
    @XmlElement
    private String ort;
    @XmlElement
    private String plz;
    @XmlElement
    private int rating;
    private double longtitude;
    private double latitude;
    private Point coordinate;
    private int placeId;
    private String osmId;

    public Stammdaten() {

    }

//Getters/Setters and other implementation

}
```

So by the documentation of hibernate spatial the contains method is available for mysql. 
And both of the objects passed to my method are a type of geometry.

So I haven't any idea why this error happens.

Any idea on this would be nice.

Comment: See [MySQL string encoding for Geometry package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440617/mysql-string-encoding-for-geometry-package/33449111)

Comment: I tried to convert the Charset. I can't make a geometry column to utf16le. And if I change the column to mediumtext and utf16le I can't save things there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking a Friend of mine, to have a look at the code brings the answer.

I didn't recognized, that Envelope isn't a Geometry. All other classes seems to extend Geometry but Envelope didn't. So the query did not get a geometry type to compare with a geometry.

Building a Polygon from my Envelope and put this into the query did the trick.